# Image is not retrieved in controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

```
 $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'string|required',
        'image.*'=>'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif'
    ]);

    $image=$request->image;
    return response()->json($image);
```

The image is not showing any file in controller of laravel 5.3

Comment: Can you show how you're submitting the image?

Comment: from postman with key image